# Facing issue with Install desktop application using pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pywinauto

I am trying to install desktop application using exe file in python script. I am trying to use pywinauto package. Facing below issue

```
app = Application(backend="win32").start(cmd_line=r'C:\Users\smsa\Downloads\xxx.exe')
  File "C:\Users\smsa\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1052, in start
raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "C:\Users\smsa\Downloads\ClearPassOnGuardInstall.exe"
Error returned by CreateProcess: (740, 'CreateProcess', 'The requested operation requires elevation.')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone suggest to help me on this.
I did start in a correct way or should i use someother package please refer

I am trying to install desktop application using exe file in python script. I am trying to use pywinauto package. Facing below issue

```
app = Application(backend="win32").start(cmd_line=r'C:\Users\smsa\Downloads\xxx.exe')
  File "C:\Users\smsa\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1052, in start
raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "C:\Users\smsa\Downloads\ClearPassOnGuardInstall.exe"
 Error returned by CreateProcess: (740, 'CreateProcess', 'The requested operation requires elevation.')
```

trying to automate desktop application for Windows.

Comment: The vast majority of the installer have silent install option like `/S` or `/q` (quiet). I would recommend to run the installer .exe file from `cmd.exe` terminal with option `/?` to get help on silent options. Of course, if your goal is GUI testing of the installer UI itself, using pywinauto makes sense anyway. I suggest silent option for normal automation case: when you only need to install 3rd-party SW.

Comment: Also the error message is pretty obvious: `"The requested operation requires elevation"` means you need to run the Python script (or higher level script) as Administrator and manually say "Yes" to UAC confirmation. If you want to disable UAC in Windows OS settings and automatically elevate privileges for the installer, it's another question that can be easily googled in ActiveState recipes.

Comment: I have downloaded the exe file and i want to automate installation process using python. Which tool is best to automate that process in python. I have tried pywinauto but i couldn't abel to proceed due to above issue. Can anyone help me to understand and how i can proceed further

Comment: Then please read the first comment. If you can say the concrete name of the installer or provide a download link, it will be very useful.

Comment: Maybe this comment will help to set OS settings properly: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/1211#issuecomment-1399213651

Comment: If you have solution for your issue, please post your own answer and accept it (check box at left side of the answer should work). This is absolutely OK.

Comment: The one you have mentioned to run as administrator solution working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty obvious: `"The requested operation requires elevation"` means you need to run the Python script (or higher level script) as Administrator and manually say "Yes" to UAC confirmation. If you want to disable UAC in Windows OS settings and automatically elevate privileges for the installer, it's another question that can be easily googled in ActiveState recipes.